LEAN 4: Apparent Contradiction re Arguments that may be referenced by 'match'
In Hitchiker's Guide to Logical Verification (2023 Standard Edition) Ch. 2, p. 16, we have this --

"The general format of recursive definitions is:

  def name (params1 : type1) . . . (params-m : type-m) : type
  | patterns1 => result1
    ...
  | patterns-n => result-n


The parameters params1 to params-m cannot be subjected to pattern matching, only the remaining arguments declared in 'type'."

However, in "Functional Programming in Lean", Sec. 1.6 "Polymorphism", we find this example:
    def length (α : Type) (xs : List α) : Nat :=
      match xs with
    | List.nil => Nat.zero
    | List.cons y ys => Nat.succ (length α ys)

as well as this one:
    def List.head? {α : Type} (xs : List α) : Option α :=
      match xs with
    | [] => none
    | y :: _ => some y

In both of the latter 2 cases, the match expression references parameters that appear in the header parameters, i.e. before the colon, as opposed to the overall type spec which appears after the colon.
Another apparent inconsistency -- in the Hitchiker's version, there is no 'match' statement; the alternates appear directly after the header.
What's the correct understanding here?

The first excerpt is incorrect. Recursive definitions are allowed to use match expressions in Lean 4. It looks like this was overlooked when the book was translated from Lean 3.
Both the syntax from the Hitchhiker's Guide and FPIL are allowed. For example, the second code block is equivalent to
    def length (α : Type) : List α -> Nat
    | List.nil => Nat.zero
    | List.cons y ys => Nat.succ (length α ys)


If so, that would clear up my confusion . . . Trouble is, those examples came from Functional Programming in Lean, which, as far as I can tell, is considered authoritative. In the Title page, the authors write that, "All code samples are tested with Lean 4 release 4.1.0". More to the point, I ran the examples myself and they run fine . . . [no errors, give correct answers . . . ]Looks like something's being missed here.

@Igott I see, I misunderstood your question and what the Hitchhiker's Guide was claiming. I've updated my answer. The gist is that both are allowed in Lean 4 (a feature that makes Agda users jealous! :-)), and the first book was translated from Lean 3, where the claim was still accurate.

Gotcha . . . clears things up.
